# Is it Possible in javascript to restrict date to specific Timezone

Tags: javascript

Is There any way to restrict my application to specific timezone and ignoring my  own local system time. Is there any way I can do globally to date object so that when ever I create a date object will create date to my specified timezone.

Comment: Eh, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Oh I have requirement to restrict to specific Timezone because all the data captured is done only in that timezone.

Comment: Consider changing your source data to use UTC. Then read those UTC dates with the appropriate Date functions, and you're good.